# Animated Pull Cord

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a pull cord effect in jQuery similar to this tutorial http://buildinternet.com/live/curtains/. I have been playing around with the code in this demo and added an animate to pull the cord backup.

However I would like to know if it is possible to create a 'Pull' action by dragging it down with the mouse and then it self-recoiling back up.

As an extra bit, is it possible to limit the amount of times it can be pulled?

Comment: Well, I don't really have much experience with jQuery / Javascript so I was able to use to the easing plugin to make it do the animation I want on click. However I want it to be draggable. And regarding the limited pulls nothing so far.

Comment: Don't use easing when dragging! It would just ruin the whole thing.

Comment: I'd use the jQuery function animate.  
Animate the width of two images - the curtains in each side, positioned absolute - left:0px and right:0px respectively

Comment: Hey T4NK3R, Thanks for that. Sorry, i won't be using the curtains part of that. It's just the pull chord im after. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GyfSQ/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I can just add animation to pull it back up now.

Comment: One more thing. is there a way i can limit how far down it can be pulled? Thanks

Comment: @Chris Till - Updated the demo, check it out! Now it can't pull over 0 for `y` and it can only be pulled once.

Comment: That's great! There is only one problem somewhere now. For some reason it is only allowing me to do it once.

Comment: Oh, I made that limit because I thought you just want it to be pulled once only

Comment: Um, I unbinded the events to limit it . You might want to count it and when it gets to 5 you can unbind the events. (`$(this).unbind()`)